# Connection UI.Dialog for c# setup project

Tags: c#, dialog, connection

[image]

I add Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.Dialog.dll and  Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.dll dlls to my project, and use this code:

```
    Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.DataConnectionDialog dcd = new Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.DataConnectionDialog();

        Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.DataSource.AddStandardDataSources(dcd);

        if (Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.DataConnectionDialog.Show(dcd) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //
        }
        else
        {
            //
        }
```

When I use this in normal windows applications, everything seems to be ok (shows standard VS dataconnection dialog with Advanced button). When I use it in SETUP PROJECT, it shows only the advanced dialog AND the OK button is disabled. Users can test the connection but can not press OK button.

Does anyone know what why this is not working?

Comment: Have you tried running the Setup Project with Admin rights? If you running from within VS, shutdown VS and start it as Admin.

Comment: VS runned as admin, and i just tryed to reun setup as admin , and NO difference :(

Comment: Which version of the ConnectionUI.dll assembly are you using, and are you referencing the same assembly from your setup and windows projects?

Comment: @ArmenKhachatryan did you get a chance to see my answer? The ok button gets enabled when the connection string is filled out correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The buttons are enabled/disabled depending on the settings.**

In this article: http://erikej.blogspot.com.au/2010/04/using-adonet-data-connection-dialog-in.html the author "hardcodes" the datasource and this consequentially disables the "Change" button.

When you set the DataSource name, the OK button should be enabled. I dug up the  `Data Connection Dialog Source Code` code to show you:
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Connection/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3863

In the Micrsost.Data.ConnectionUI.Dialog project, open the DataConnectionDialog.cs class and you can see this is the event:

```
private void ConfigureAcceptButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
acceptButton.Enabled = (ConnectionProperties != null) ? ConnectionProperties.IsComplete : false;
}
catch
{
acceptButton.Enabled = true;
}
}
```

The above event is hooked up from the ConnectionProperties method and is invoked each time the PropertyChange event fires:

```
properties.PropertyChanged += new EventHandler(ConfigureAcceptButton);
```

To get the OK button enabled you will need to satisfy the ConnectionProperties.IsComplete condition.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem as you when I ran the DataConnectionDialog from a PowerPoint plugin.

The problem is that the SqlConnectionUIControl must be run in a STA thread.
Here is the code I got working.

Load button is clicked, launch the data connector in a thread.

```
private void dataSourceSelectionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Thread browseThread = new Thread(promptForConnectionString);
  browseThread.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
  browseThread.Start();  
}
```

Opening the dialog.

```
public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

private void promptForDataConnection()
{
  DataConnectionDialog dataConnection = new DataConnectionDialog();
  DataConnectionConfiguration connectionConfiguration = new DataConnectionConfiguration(null);
  connectionConfiguration.LoadConfiguration(dataConnection);

  if (DataConnectionDialog.Show(dataConnection) == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    connectionConfiguration.SaveConfiguration(dataConnection);

    this.ConnectionString = dataConnection.ConnectionString;
  }
}
```

If this doesn't help, picking up the [DataConnectionDialog Source](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Connection/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3863) might.

Answer (score 0):

I not able to solve this problem by running VS2008 as Admin. I solve this problem by disable "Enabled the Visual Studio hosting process" option in the Winform project.